# Amplitude of the steady-state response to undamped spring-damper system subject to forcing function $p_oe^{-at}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, vibrations

I am trying to find the amplitude of the steady-state solution to the following undamped equation of motion:

$$m \ddot{u} + k u = p_0 e^{-at}$$

The question is asking to prove that the steady-state amplitude is:

$$\frac{u_o}{(u_{st})_o} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2/\omega_n^2}} $$

I solved the particular solution to be:

$$u_{p} = \frac{p_o}{{m\omega_n^2}(1+\frac{a^2}{\omega_n^2})}$$

I solved the maximum static amplitude to be:
$$(u_{st})_o = \frac{p_o}{k} $$

I found that the total solution is:

$$u(t) = \frac{p_o}{m\omega_n^2(1 + \frac{a^2}{\omega_n^2})}(\frac{a}{\omega_n}\sin(\omega_nt) - \cos(\omega_nt) + e^{-at}) $$

I used the method of undetermined coefficients and the boundary conditions $u(0)=0$ and $\dot{u}(0)=0$.

I'm just not sure how to proceed from here. From the problem, it states that $u_o$ is the maximum amplitude of $u(t)$. Please advise!

Note: I used the formula $\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$ for substitution of $k$ values to $\omega_n$.

Comment: Without damping, there can be any steady-state amplitude.  The forcing decays, so at large times it us irrelevant.  If you add a friction term but leave the decaying forcing, the steady-state amplitude us zero, because everything damps away.